# I'm trying to make an internet radio alarm clock

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to make an alarm clock which opens a website. I have something which works but it is imprecise and generally quite ugly

```
Manipulate[
If[
Refresh[DateList[], UpdateInterval -> 60][[4 ;; 5]] == {hour, 
minute},
SystemOpen["http://www.fipradio.fr/player"]
];
Grid[
{{"current hour", 
Dynamic@Refresh[DateList[][[4]], UpdateInterval -> 1], 
"alarm hour", hour}, {"current minute", 
Dynamic@Refresh[DateList[][[5]], UpdateInterval -> 1], 
"alarm minute", minute}}
, Alignment -> Left]
, {hour, 0, 24, 1}, {minute, 0, 60, 5}]
```

Any suggestions for how to do this better?

Edit: I have made my working example a little prettier

Comment: Have you seen `RunScheduledTask` ?

Comment: @SimonWoods At least in Windows, `SystemOpen[]` doesn't work straight from a Scheduled Task

Comment: @SimonWoods No I had not! It seems like it should be perfect but I can't get it to work so far.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @mfvonh I'm using a mac

Comment: Just curious - why are you trying to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: @Ymareth, mainly its just for fun but to be fair I could not actually find an app that did what I want. If you are asking why Mathematica and not another language, then its only because I don't know any other languages well enough to do this.

Comment: @belisarius, ah okay. I didn't know that. Sorry for the false hope, user12876

Comment: @user12876 OS X has cron jobs built in, which you can manage from the terminal. You just need to Google for "cron jobs OS X", and "how to open a website command line".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [cron](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_cron_jobs) for this.

In Mathematica:

```
RunScheduledTask[
 StartProcess @ {"open", "/Applications/Safari.app"};
 Pause @ 2; (* give Safari time to load *)
 Run @ "osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to open location \"http://www.fipradio.fr/player\"'",
 10(* repeat interval, low for demonstration *),
 AbsoluteTime @ {2014, 10, 28, 1, 27, 0}(* start time, can be in past *)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this code what you wanted?

```
Manipulate[
 If[Refresh[DateList[], UpdateInterval -> 60][[4 ;; 5]] == {hour, minute}, 
   SystemOpen["http://xianyungu.com"]];
 Row[{hour, ":", minute}], {{hour, 12}, 0, 23, 1}, {{minute, 0}, 0, 59, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It still suffers from the use of UpdateInterval -> 60. It certainly is not a big issue and the code works fine but I expect there is a more elegant solution.